# scikit-learn: projecting SVM weights of Prinicpal Components to original image space

Tags: scikit-learn, pca, medical

I did a PCA on my 3D image datasets, and used the first n PCs as my features in a linear SVM. I have SVM weights for each PC. Now, I want to project the PC weights into original image space to find what  regions of the image were more discriminative in the classification process. I used the inverse_transform PCA method on the weight vector. However, the resulting image only has positive values, whereas the SVM weights were both positive and negative. This makes me think if my approach is a valid one. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I would suggest that you link the used acronyms to their dictionary definition, make the procedure needed to reproduce the problem [more detailed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to find [Stack Exchange community](http://stackexchange.com/sites) where is this kind of rather abstract (probably related to math or signal processing theory) problems solved. Don't cross post, just find the best fit by reading the site's `Help > Help Center > Asking > What topics can I ask about here` and then use `flag` button and let moderator know that you want it moved

Answer (score 0):

I have a program that does this projection in image space. The thing to realise is that the weights themselves do not define the 'discrimination' weights (as also termed in [this paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3722452)). You need the sum of the inputs weighted by their kernel coefficients.

Consider this toy example:
Class `A` has 2 vectors: `a1=(1,1)` and `a2=(2,2)`
Class `B` has 2 vectors: `b1=(2,4)` and `a3=(4,2)`.

If you draw this, you can construct the decision boundary by hand: it's the line of points `(x,y)` where `x+y == 5`. My SVM program finds the solution where `w_a1 == 0` (no support vector), `w_a2 == -1)` and `w_b1 == w_b2 == 1/2`, and `bias == -5`.

Now you can construct the projection vector `p = a2*w_a2 + b1*w_b1 + b2*w_b2` = `-1*(2,2) + 1/2*(2,4) + 1/2*(4,2)` = `(1,1)`.

In other words, every point should be projected onto the line `y == x`, and for a new vector `v` the inner product `<v,p>` is below 5 for class A vectors, and above 5 for class B vectors. You can centre the result around 0 by adding the bias.